# Set content of DIV - in Bootstrap component

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

OK, so here's what I'm trying to do (rather a lot more complicated than what you'd guess from the title...) :

- My (test) page is : `http://83.212.101.132/betdk/home/two`
- I have integrated this Bootstrap snippet : http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/login-form-with-css-3d-transforms

As you can see, there's the login form on the right side. When you click that gray-ish little triangle at the top right (or left) corner, the form flips.

Now, the thing is :

**How** can I set some content (centered - e.g. a little icon) INSIDE this gray triangle? (instead of that awkward "sign in -->" thing...)

Tried using `content:` or something along these lines, but since I'm not such a ... CSS guru, I haven't managed anything.

So,... any ideas?

Comment: I take it you want the text to be at a certain angle then? A good example of this is the 'Fork Me at Github' however it's just an image as that is the simplest way of doing what you require.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set some content with the `:after` pseudo-element:

```
#triangle-topright:after {
    content: "A";
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    text-indent: 0;
}

#triangle-topleft:after {
    content: "B";
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    top: -50px;
    text-indent: 0;
}
```

Then you could use an icon font to put an icon in there.